# Part of birth in applying to a university

Tags: expressions

Actually I am applying to a university and there is a part where I have the following:

> Né(e) le:
>
> A:
>
> Commune:

So can any one tell me what I am supposed to write in each, especially in the second one?

Answer in English please because I am not good at French.

Comment: The second field, which should written with an accent *À*, looks redundant with the third one.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, *À* means "in" when asked after the birth date, i.e. the location where you were born.

The third field (*commune*) is an administrative division in France, but it might not have a strict equivalent in other countries. That's a town/municipality and what is stated as *place of birth* in many documents.

If you want to provide different information in these last fields, you might give your hour/minute of birth in the *à* one, because *à* can also introduce that information (that is never asked for by universities though...)

Comment: I may write the name of the country for  à and the name of the town for commune.

Comment: You can't. *À* doesn't refer to a country (outside islands). That would be *En* or in a few cases *Au/Aux*.